# Does the 'Dogman' - a half-man, half-dog hybrid - exist?

Tags: cryptozoology

The 'Dogman' is a half-man, half-dog hybrid that has many sightings in every state of the US, similar to Bigfoot. A 13-year old boy in Kentucky was reported in the news as being killed by a "canine-type" creature, but officials were unable to identify what it was even when they had the DNA. People were talking about how the boy was killed by 'Dogman'.

[Here is a news clip of the incident in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8q96yHkKCs). Most of the comments on the video mention the Dogman, alleging it to be responsible for the boy's death.

**Does the Dogman really exist?**

Answer (score 3):

The news clip itself mentions neither DNA testing nor any supposed Dogman.

However, **WKYT** reported on 12th August 2020 (6 months later):

> [**Knott County boy killed by pack of wild dogs**](https://www.wkyt.com/2020/08/12/knott-county-boy-killed-by-pack-of-wild-dogs/)
>
> KNOTT CO., Ky. (WKYT) - State police say 13-year-old Corey Godsey was killed by a pack of dogs.
>
> It happened back in February in the Emmalena community of Knott County.
>
> At the time, the state medical examiner’s office confirmed Corey was killed in some kind of animal attack but wasn’t able to determine the specific animal involved.
>
> During the investigation, state police say multiple dogs were found living on an old mine site near the area Corey’s body was found.
>
> KSP says the dogs were taken to the Kentucky River Animal Shelter where DNA specimens were collected and compared to evidence.
>
> State police say the lab comparisons indicated that specimens from several of the dogs matched those found on Corey.
>
> We’re told the investigation is still ongoing and we’ll keep you updated.

So the speculation that a so-called Dogman exists, isn't supported by the case you cited.